# ruby on rails sql - joins parent to find by parent data

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Event has many jobs.

**How do I find all jobs that belong to an event that was created_at a specific month?**

I tried this, and the syntax looks good to me

```
@jobs = Job.joins(:event)
           .where(events: {"starts_at BETWEEN ? AND ?", Time.now.beginning_of_month, Time.now.end_of_month})
           .where(member_id: @member)`
```

but it gives an error:

[image: rec]

Comment: What RDMBS are you using?

Comment: it is postgresql

Comment: A PostgreSQL way could be to extract year and month from events.starts_at and use Date.current.year and month respectively to apply the filter `Job.joins(:event).where("DATE_PART('year', events.starts_at)::integer = ? AND DATE_PART('month', events.starts_at)::integer = ?", Date.current.year, Date.current.month)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two ways to solve that SyntaxError:

```
Job.joins(:event)
   .where("events.starts_at BETWEEN ? AND ?", Time.now.beginning_of_month, Time.now.end_of_month)
   .where(member_id: @member)

Job.joins(:event)
   .where(events: { starts_at: Time.now.beginning_of_month..Time.now.end_of_month })
   .where(member_id: @member)
```

One is to use "the string way". The name of the table followed by the name of the column and the operator binding the start and end dates.

The other one is to use hash arguments. First passing the table name as the hash key, containing the column where the value is a range between the start end date.

---

Although if you're getting the whole current month, you can use `all_month` for that:

```
(Time.now.beginning_of_month..Time.now.end_of_month) == Time.now.all_month 
# true
```

Comment: really cool! thank you! and is there a performance difference in the string way VS the hash way?

Comment: I don't think so. At least isn't specified in the [docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-where).